# Errors with running code that works on another computer

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am not really sure what is going on. I get the following errors when I run 'node ./controllers/db.controller.js'

```
1) (...).then(...).catch is not a function 

2) TypeError: resolve is not a function
```

```
PS P:\GitHub\arkadbot> node .\controllers\db.controller.js
(node:11944) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Connected successfully to server
{ user_id: 111 }
TypeError: findDocuments(...).then(...).catch is not a function
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\controllers\db.controller.js:73:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at dbController (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\controllers\db.controller.js:35:11)
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\controllers\db.controller.js:132:11
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:410:17
    at executeCallback (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:402:9)
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:286:5
    at connectCallback (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:265:5)
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:379:5
    at Server.connectHandler (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\server.js:298:9)
find documents test 0
Found the following records
P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: resolve is not a function
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\db\bittrex\find_documents.js:29:11
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:410:17
    at executeCallback (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:402:9)
    at handleCallback (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:128:55)
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\cursor_ops.js:224:62
    at handleCallback (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:128:55)
    at completeClose (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:898:14)
    at Cursor.close (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:917:10)
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\cursor_ops.js:224:23
    at handleCallback (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:204:5)
PS P:\GitHub\arkadbot>
```

```
C:\>node -v
v12.8.1

C:\>npm -v
6.10.2
```

If I comment out the .catch in db.controller and change resolve to Promise.resolve in findDocuments, then the file runs fine. However we need the .catch in case of issues with the database or what not.

The code works just fine for my buddy who wrote it. I have done npm install, uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs, deleted and reinstalled the node modules,and moving code around. I am not entirely sure what to do to fix this problem other than that. From what we can tell, when we run 'node ls' we have the same packages and what not in there as well.

```
//===========================
// Import Libraries
//===========================

const assert = require('assert')
const Promise = require('promise')

//===========================
// Find Documents
//===========================
const findDocuments = function(db, collectionName, key, filterTerm) {         
  // Get the documents collection
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName)
    let filter = {};
    filter[key] = filterTerm;
    console.log(filter)
    switch (collectionName) {
      case "api_keys":
        collection.find(filter).toArray((error, docs)  => {
          if (error) reject (error)
          console.log('find documents test 0')
          assert.equal(error, null)
          console.log("Found the following records")
          resolve(docs)
        })
      break
      case "orders":
        collection.find({tradeId:field}).toArray((error, docs)  => {
          if (error) reject (error)
          assert.equal(error, null)
          console.log("Found the following records")
          resolve(docs)
        })
      break
      default: console.log('Insert Document Default Test')
    }
  })
}

module.exports = findDocuments
```

```
//===========================
// Database Controller
//===========================

const Promise = require('promise')

const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const assert = require('assert')

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'

// Database Name
const dbName = 'arkadbot'

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new mongoClient(url)

// Database Services
const findDocuments = require('../db/find_documents.js')

// Database Collections
const order = require('../models/order.js')
const API = require('../models/api.js')

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
// Need to figure out how to pass { useNewUrlParser: true } to connect ***
const dbController = function dbController(serviceName, collectionName, exchange, userId, userAPIKey, userAPISecretKey, orderObject, db) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      collectionName = collectionName.toLowerCase()

    if (serviceName === 'find') {
        return findDocuments(db, collectionName, exchange, orderObject)
        .then(response => {
           console.log("Successfully found document from " + collectionName)
           resolve(response)
        })
        .catch(error => reject(error))
    } else  {
        console.log("There is an error with the service requested")
    }

    })

   }

module.exports = dbController


client.connect(function(error) {
   assert.equal(null, error)
   const db = client.db(dbName)

   return dbController('find','api_keys', 'user_id', 111, null, null, null, db)
   .then(response => {
      console.log("response", response)
      return dbController('find','api_keys', 'user_id', 123, db)
      .then(response2 => {
         console.log("response2", response2)
         client.close()
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

changed the promise statements to be const Promise = require('Promise') and updated any lowercase promise to be Promise in both files. I now have a differentish error as its dbcontroller instead of find documents

**New error:**

```
PS P:\GitHub\arkadbot> node .\controllers\db.controller.js
(node:22940) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Connected successfully to server
{ user_id: 111 }
P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\server.js:301
          throw err;
          ^

TypeError: dbController(...).then(...).catch is not a function
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\controllers\db.controller.js:142:10
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:410:17
    at executeCallback (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:402:9)
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:286:5
    at connectCallback (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:265:5)
    at P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:379:5
    at Server.connectHandler (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\server.js:298:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (P:\GitHub\arkadbot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:377:12)
PS P:\GitHub\arkadbot>
```

**Issue resolved! Solution:** 
Using native Promise and removing const promise/Promise = require('promise') statements fixed the error.

Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: It's better to you provide node version and complete stack traces to help others find an issue.

Comment: just to be sure, are you using the same build process, ie the same `package.json` file and commands?  ive had issues like this when incorrectly using es6 code, babel and webpack etc.

Comment: What is this: `const promise = require('promise')`?  Is there a reason you aren't using the built-in `Promise`?  Also, what node.js version in both installations?

Comment: Will update with the complete stack trace and node version 

Yes everything is the same as far as package.json. Everything seems to install fine when i do npm install

Comment: what do you mean by built in promise jfriend00? As in the P should be capital in the require('promise') statement?

Comment: changed to have const Promise = require('Promise') and got a different error (posted above) still doesnt seem to like .then or .catch

Comment: @jfriend00 wow thank you! I honestly didnt realize i didnt need to require promise. Not sure why/how i came about doing const promise = require ('promise'). Getting rid of that seems to of resolved the errors! If you put that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any modern version of node.js, Promises are built-in.  So, there is no need to do:

```
const promise = require('promise')
```

unless you're specifically trying to use a different promise library than what node.js has built in.  And, if you were trying to do that, then you should use it consistently and some of your code uses `promise` and some uses `Promise` which would be mixing the two.

So, I'd suggest getting rid of `const promise = require('promise')` and using the built-in `Promise` everywhere (note you have to change `promise` to `Promise` in your code to properly reference the built-in Promise library).

Answer (score 1):

In the second listing you import `promise` and later use `Promise`.

Comment: what line are you seeing that I feel like i dont see Promise anywhere in db.controller

Comment: ah honestly i didnt think about that. So I should be doing const Promise = require('Promise') instead? I can try that quickly

Comment: I updated to const Promise = require('Promise') and now I get a new error. Posted above

Comment: I think the package name should be lowercase p, but the variable name and references to it should be consistent. eg `const Promise = require('promise')` and then `return new Promise(...` etc

Comment: with const Promise = require('promise') i get the error i added above in my original post

Also updated the code in my original post to reflect that change